# python-shell problem with sync inside javascript

Tags: javascript, python, python-multithreading

I'm using **[python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell)** to run a **Python code** that return some messages inside a **JavaScript environment**, but the messages come **out of sync**. The **first message** returns at the **right moment**, but then **all other messages** comes out **together** at the end, not one by one.

When I run the `test.py` alone the messages come in the right way, which possibly means that is not a problem with my python code. Despite all other messages is logged together, the time when they are executed inside the python code is right, what can be seeing by the `time:` inside each message.

But what happens in my browser environment is the message `<2>FIRST TEST` logged first, and then `<3>TEST` and `<4>MORE TEST` are logged together after 10 seconds.

[image]

This is my python code `test.py`:

```py
import sys
import time
import threading

def test():
    start = time.time()
    end1 = time.time()
    print("<2>FIRST TEST time: {}".format(end1 - start))

    time.sleep(5)
    end2 = time.time()
    print("<3>TEST time: {}".format(end2 - start))

    time.sleep(5)
    end3 = time.time()
    print("<4>MORE TEST time: {}".format(end3 - start))

x = threading.Thread(target=test)
x.start()
sys.stdout.flush()
```

This is my JavaScript code `execPyShell.ts`:

```js
const exec: () => void = () => {
    console.log('Start')
    let pyshell = new PythonShell('./engine/test.py');
    let newLogs: string[] = [];

    pyshell.on('message', function(message: string) {
        console.log(message);
    })

    pyshell.end(function (err: any) {
    if (err){
        throw err;
    };
        console.log('Finished');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I forgot that I had to add

```py
sys.stdout.flush()
```

After every `print()` called to force it to flush the buffer.